# Iterate files recursively

Tags: powershell, loops, filesystems

I have a powershell script that iterates files from a certain network directory. In this directory, there are aroud 190 sub directories, each containing several files.

I use this to perform the job:

```
get-childitem -Path $pathFilesOrig -Recurse -Force -Include *.pdf, *.csv | ForEach {
  write-host "INFO:File name: $_"
}
```

However, it does not loop in certain directories, whereas there are valid files in it and access rights are fine (I can access those files through windows explorer manually).

I have tried the following to check if I can at least iterate every directory:

```
get-childitem -Path $pathFilesOrig -Recurse -Force | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | ForEach {
  write-host "INFO:Dir name: $_"
}
```

When I do it, the script displays every directory.

Now I do it to list files in each directory:

```
get-childitem -Path $pathFilesOrig -Recurse -Force | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | ForEach {
  write-host "INFO:Dir name: $_"
  $tmpDirName = $pathFilesOrig + $_.Name
  get-childitem -Path $tmpDirName | ForEach {
    Write-Host "INFO:File name: $_"
```

And in this case, again, some directories are missing.

There is not even the result of the second line `write-host "INFO:Dir name: $_"` which was working fine previously.

I don't understand, and I am certainly missing something...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your problem has to do with [the `-Include` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-5.1#parameters) which filters items after the provider has collected all of the objects versus `-Filter` which handles it at enumeration, i.e., when it's getting the objects first.  You can further improve performance by only enumerating files using the `-File` parameter.

```bsh
#requires -Version 3

Get-ChildItem -Path $pathFilesOrig -Filter *.pdf, *.csv -File -Force -Recurse
```

If this command fails to resolve your problem, I suspect you actually do have a privileges problem since `-Force` will get hidden directories, but does not supersede access.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, I have an older version of powershell and I cannot change it on this server. In the versionj I have, I can only filter one thing, that's why I used Include. For now, I will bypass my problem by encapsulating the powershell in another script (bash) that will do the listing.

Comment: @LaurentC. v5.1 is supported on 2008R2 (which I'm assuming you're on).  I'd strongly advise getting off v2 from purely a security standpoint.